# ember own backbutton implementation

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In the latest version of ember, what is the best way to implement a backbutton functionality.
I mean, not only using the browsers backbutton. I have my own backbutton in the top left corner of my application. 
If the previous page in the browsers history is outside my application, then I want to go to my applications main page instead.
There are numerous suggestions on how to solve this out there, but they are rather old. How to do this properly in the latest version of ember?

I think the `window.history.go(-1);` will not do it in all cases.

I guess I have to keep my own history stack? How do I hook into every transition to maintain the stack?

Comment: i did this once by setting the window location in a value in a cookie every time the user clicked a link in the application. i then did some string matching to determine where the user came from. this was to determine if a user came from my ember application to another part of the site which was not ember. worked out well

Comment: I want to use ember functionality and the ember router

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but it's pretty easy to implement:

In your routes use the event `willTransition` to know when the user will make a transition and, before fulfilling it, store the actual path in a `service` (I recommend a `service` because you can use it in all the routes just by injecting it). Then you only have to request that `service` the previous route to transition to when the button is clicked. To avoid boilerplate code, you can make a `mixin` for that `willTransition` event, so you'll only need to add to your routes the `mixin` instead of repeating the same code again and again